# How to get specified space between radio button and the radio button text?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, spacing

I have the following code`<asp:RadioButton runat="server" Text="Male"></asp:RadioButton>`
I want a gap between the radio button and the radio button text, I made the following changes in the **text field**(prefixed a space) `Text=" Male"`. However, I don't feel this is the most efficient way. A better way out?

Answer (score 7):

Using CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] { margin-right: 5px; }
```